# How to display google maps in a very large window?

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

Using iframe to display google maps in hres. Lets say 10000x10000 don't work, because google dont allow you to do this. That's what it says when I open the document in internet explorer. I am doing this because I want to make a big screenshots of google maps and then stitch them in photoshop. This will make a big satellite map  which I can use to explore off-road routes with my bike without the need to have access to the internet.

Please if anyone have any ideas; maybe an html  code which works?

Comment: Capturing "big screenshots and stitch them in photoshop" sounds like something that woudl be against the terms of use.

Comment: what else can i do ecxept that , in order not loose my way in the woods and stack their at night .....bears  and wolfs will eat me))))) it seams this the best and the only way to explore wild areas witout internet connection .... witch otherwise dont exist in remote areas......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned @geocodezip there are certain restrictions you should be aware of. The Terms of Service has the following sentence (paragraph 10.1):

> No access to APIs or Content except through the Service. You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

Also paragraph 10.5 says:

> No derivative works. You will not modify or create a derivative work based on any Content unless expressly permitted to do so under these Terms. For example, the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles; (ii) stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation; or (iii) tracing or copying the copyrightable elements of Google’s maps or building outlines and creating a new work, such as a new mapping or navigation dataset.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions